# Редактирование на странице

Tags: php

Сейчас делаю редактирование на странице сайта, если я зашел в админ панель под своим логином и паролем (использую сессию) на странице сайта к каждой статье вверху появляется блок с кнопками (редактировать, удалить, активировать/деактивировать и так далее).

Пример кода:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['admin']): ?>
  <div class="but_header">
    <a href="../admin/edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><div class ="edit">Редактировать</div></a>
    <a href="../admin/delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><div class ="delete">Удалить</div></a>
  </div>
<? endif ; ?>
```

Вопрос заключается в том: правильно ли я  делаю, или есть какой-то лучший способ вывединня такого блока с кнопками ?

Такой способ безопасный или нет ?
Может сделать какую-то дополнительную проверку, пароля или что-то другое...

Answer (score 1):

Проверку авторизации обязательно должна быть в admin/edit.php и /admin/delete.php. Иначе по прямой ссылке кто угодно сможет редактировать и удалять данные.
Лучше ее сделать в одном месте и подключать в этих 2-х файлах. Или реализовать одну общую точку входа в admin например так:

```
<a href="../admin/index.php?action=edit&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><div class ="edit">Редактировать</div></a>
<a href="../admin/index.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><div class ="delete">Удалить</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

По моему опыту, разумней использовать отдельную админ-панель, а не формировать кнопки действия непосредственно на фронте. Собственно, чтобы не мешать все в одной банке, отдельно и выделяют фронтенд и бэкенд (хотя, лучше фронт / апи / бэк).

С точки зрения защищенности, я бы добавил еще хттп-авторизацию на каталог админ. А так, если у вас проверяется существование сессии, то особой разницы нет - будет человек идти по /admin/edit.php или /admin/index.php?action=edit , т.е. дело вкуса. Я бы использовал настройки адресации (типа чпу) и писал /admin/page/edit/{id} .

Answer (score 0):

Это удаление можно красиво обернуть в AJAX запросы на сервер. С указанием к примеру параметров таких как ID или чего-то там что надо редактировать и токена администриатора.

1. Токен даст большу степень защищенности
2. AJAX поможет выполнить сие чудо без перезагрузки страницы. Быстро и красиво.

А вообще для построения Фронтенда я юзаю шаблонизаторы.

потом удобнее рерактировать верствку. Через какое-то время.